# Не могу получить доступ к первому элементу строки

Tags: python, строки

```
search = "-";
f = open('MyText.txt', 'r')
text=f.read()
text=text.replace(" ","")
listofstrings=text.split(".", len(text))
counter=0
searchcount=0
while counter<len(listofstrings):
    if listofstrings[counter][0]==search:

    searchcount+=1
print(listofstrings[counter])
counter+=1

if searchcount==0:
    print("\nНе нашел(\n")
else:
    print("Было найдено: ")
    print(searchcount)
f.close()
```

if listofstrings[counter][0]==search: в этой строке ошибка
интерпретатор говорит что это значение вне диапазона, текст - лорем

Comment: Как вы думаете, сколько элементов у пустой строки?

Comment: кст, а зачем тут `istofstrings=text.split(".", len(text))` второй параметр?